# Low ICC for Healthy but Large Difference from Diseased

Tags: variance, reliability, intraclass-correlation

I have a test I am interested in further investigating for diagnostic purposes. The test involves 6 trials, giving a mean result and variance for each person. What we have found through Mann-Whitney testing is that the variance, not the mean, is significantly higher in a diseased population (n=29) than the healthy population (n=98). Also, a pooled variance F-test of both groups is significantly different as well (pooled variance of 2.0 vs 1.1 for diseased and normal, respectively, F-critical = 1.6, actual = 1.8).

We have a dataset of 40 people who completed the test twice, with a very very low retest reliability (based on an ICC of 0.0) between an individual's two variances. Essentially, each healthy person can reasonably range from a variance of 0 -> 2 units of the test. Due to this very low retest reliability, our statistician believes we should not look at this test further.

However, I am struggling with the idea that what equates to a random baseline score means the test has no predictive value and should not be investigated further. The baseline scores are not entirely random, as only 5% of healthy people fall above a variance of 2.2. 40% of our diseased group's variances fall above that 95th percentile; the average variance for the diseased group is 1.7.

So my question is, if anyone could help me, is there a better way to present this data for healthy people than an ICC? Is part of the problem that I am trying to calculate an ICC for a variance measure when typically it is used for a mean score? It seems clear to me that there is some interaction happening here, based on all inter-subject testing.